# Rails 3 Auto Select from Collect_select

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, drop-down-menu

I have the following associations:

```
Town -> has_many :outlets
User -> belongs_to :town
Outlet -> belongs_to :town, has_many :problems
Problem -> belongs_to :outlet
```

In the Outlets Page, I want to be able to click a button that will take me to the **New Problem** page. In the 'New Problem Page' I have the following collection_select:

```
f.collection_select :outlet_id, Outlet.all, :id, :name
```

However, if I clicked the button that took me here from the Outlet Page, I want the correct outlet to already be selected and greyed out so the user can't change it.

I was thinking I could possibly do this with a custom route, that will accept the :outlet_id as a param, but I wasn't sure how to do this, or even if this is the best option.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, you have something like

```
@problem = Problem.new
```

try

```
@problem = Problem.new({ outlet_id: params[:outlet_id] })
```

And the form helpers should take care of it.

You could also try to do it as a nested RESTful resource in which case the url would look something like **/outlets/5/problems/new**  and rails would automatically set params[:outlet_id] to 5..

Your route for this would look like:

```
resources :outlets do
  resources :problems    
end
```

Comment: So in the link_to tag, what would I set as the url param?

BTW thanks for the fast reply, I'm new to Ruby and the Stack Exchange community is fantastic :D

Comment: From your rails directory, do "rake routes".. You'll see something like new_outlet_problems..  So in your helper you'd do new_outlet_problems_path(@outlet) where @outlet is the outlet object or id.

Comment: I've now got the link working, but when I get taken to the New Problem Page, the Outlet ID is still the default in the select box, and not the outlet I want

Comment: Look in your rails log at the params - can you see the params[:outlet_id] ?  Did you change the definition in your problem controller for creating the "new" object?

Comment: You sir are a genius.. I'd forgotten to adjust the new controller. Is there any way I can get it to grey out the select box (to make it unchangeable) if the outlet_id param is set?

Comment: You could add some logic to your form so if value is not set, show a select helper.  If not use a hidden_field and just print out the value..

Comment: I'm sorry to be so 'noobish' but what kind of logic would that be?

Comment: just <% if @problem.outlet.nil? %> ... select box  <% else %>  f.hidden_field and then Outlet: <%= @problem.outlet.name %> or whatever it actually is.